# Kotlin return list based on type property

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I need to extract a list of Items based on some of their types ("typeA", "typeB", "typeC", "typeD" out of 20 cases). How I can do it on an elegant way. Without creating an `Invalid` type which is unwanted.

On java I would create an empty list and have a `foreach`, skipping for the unwanted cases. I have no idea how to do it on kotlin because `map()` needs to return something and creating `Invalid` type is out of scope for this. Having the java solution does not sound correct.

*Edited

I will give an example:
We have a list of desserts and we are filtering for "ice-cream" and "cake" types, I just created the code below:

```
private fun getDessertsByType(dessertsFromBackend: List<Dessert>) {
val myList = mutableListOf<Dessert>()
for (item in dessertsFromBackend) {
  if (item.getId() === "ice-cream") {
    myList.add(item)
  }
  if (item.getId() === "cake") {
    myList.add(item)
  } else { //We do not need to care for anything else
    continue
  }
}
}
```

Comment: At a time you want only one type of item? Or the combination of types?

Comment: *based on some of their types* it's not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: Could you provided an example of an input and the expected output

Comment: what about `mapNotNull` and all your valid types are returned, whereas the "invalid" one return `null`? `yourList.mapNotNull { when (it) { is ValidType -> it; else -> /*invalid */ null } }` or just `filter` them: `yourList.filter { it is ValidType }`

Comment: Thank you all I just edited with an example right now

Comment: Note that `==` is the `.equals` in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) is for generating a new output based on an input

For your example I'd say that what you want to do is actually [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) your input:

```
private fun getDessertsByType(dessertsFromBackend: List<Dessert>) =
    dessertsFromBackend.filter {
        (item.getId() == "ice-cream") 
        || (item.getId() == "cake")
        || ... }
    }
}
```

Notice that your code will probably look cleaner with [`when`](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Comment: True. Never copy&paste from a question

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried myself but try doing this.

```
dessertsFromBackend.filter { it.id == "ice-cream" || it.id == "cake" }
```